# How should I implement peer-to-peer networking in C++?

Tags: c++, sockets

I have previously implemented server/client networking programs in C, but I have never done peer-to-peer program or any socket programming in C++.

For peer-to-peer, I guess I would have to create multiple threads and manage incoming and outgoing connections, since each program will work like a client and a server at the same time, right?

What would be a good way to implement this in C++? I believe C++ does not natively support threading...

Comment: What are the target platforms? Windows, Linux, MacOS, embedded, multiple,... etc This will determine much of the technical choices.

Comment: What do you mean "peer-to-peer" (as opposed to server/client)? TCP/IP is always client/server (client is who calls connect, server calls listen+accept).

Comment: What I meant 'peer-to-peer' was that all application will act like servers/client and they will communicate with each other. So there is no central server in this case.

Comment: Linux is my target platforms by the way.

Comment: There are multiple server designs, and the "correct" design changes a lot based on the platform capabilities and, especially, on the protocol being implemented.  Without a real use case, it's hard to give good advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not required to use multiple threads.  An alternative is to use a single thread, and multiplex the sockets using select() (or poll() or epoll() or etc).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the [boost.asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) library which is good for multiple socket connctions (either threaded or not...)

Answer (score 0):

Any code that would be valid in C is also valid in C++. So you can use the same socket API there and the same threading API (but the [Boost](http://www.boost.org) wrappers might indeed be much more convenient).

Also C++ will natively support threading sometime towards the end of this year (the standard is already written and expected to be voted on by ISO later this year). Of course it may take some time to show up in your compiler/stdlibc++ (but gcc/gnu stdlibc++ already implements it except for language support for thread-local storage (which it does support, but using the older compiler-specific way)). For compilers that don't support it, the boost version is mostly compatible to the proposed standard anyway.